# Question on binomial coefficient

Tags: binomial-coefficients

What will be the coefficient of $x^{99}$
in the following:
$(x+1)(x+2)(x+3).....(x+100)$
Please help. I am stuck on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zeroes of the given polynomial are $-1,-2,...-100$. By Viete formulas for $$ax^{100} + bx^{99}+....=0$$ 
we have $$ x_1+x_2+...x_{100} = -{b\over a}$$
so $$-b = -1-2-...-100 = -{100\cdot 101\over 2} \Longrightarrow b= 5050$$

Comment: You bastard, you did it again!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to pick $x$ from every bracket apart from one giving
\begin{eqnarray*}
(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)\cdots(x+100)=x^{100}+ x^{99}\color{red}{\left(\sum_{i=1}^{100}i\right)}+\cdots
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: this is the same as choosing combinations of (100-1) factors from 100